# why can't I see the full array of my mysql data for php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about this ....

```
$query = 'SELECT * 
            FROM EXAMPLE';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
print_r($row);
```

This has the data of the first row [0] => 1 [id]=> 1... blah, blah  but now I'm just wondering, what about the other table data? Is it a php safety to not display the "full array" of all the data inside EXAMPLE table? Just the first row of the data?

This is just out of curiosity.

I know if I want to see specific part of the entire data I can do a while loop.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
   echo $row['text'].'<br>';
 }
```

Comment: have you tried mysql_fetch_row?

Comment: what do you mean by "the full array"  Do you mean all the data that is contained in the result?  If that is what you mean, then you are correct that you have to loop through the data to get it out.

Comment: Other PHP database technologies (eg PDO) support fetching a rowset at once, but not the native mysql functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array only returns one row of data. In your second example you are calling mysql_fetch_array over and over for every row.

Comment: I see, that's what I wanted to verify. Thanks. I think I should have just consulted the mysql website next time...

Comment: @user672178 You should accept an answer, Dark Slipstream has given you a solution and I have explained what you were doing wrong. You also have not accepted an answer for any of your previous questions.

Comment: Oh sorry about that ben, I'm not sure what it means to "accept" an answer. I'm new to this kind of ... style of "forum" Sorry about that. How do I accept?

Answer (score 1):

To output all your data, do the following:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE';
$result = mysql_query( $query );
print( '<pre>' ); // Preserve Whitespace/Newlines

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
    print_r($row);

print( '</pre>' );
```

If you want to see a specific part of the entire data, do the following:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    echo $row['text'].'<br>';
```